# Why does deferred.resolve not behave as specified in the q manual?

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

This may be a stupid question, but I am unable to wrap my head around this.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
function throwError() {
    throw Error("can't touch this.");
}

var def = q.defer();

def.promise.then(
  function() {
    console.log("no error");
  },
  function() {
    console.log("error");
  }
);

q.fcall(throwError).then(def.resolve, def.resolve).done();
```

In my opinion this should print `error`. Instead, it prints `no error`.
The `q` manual states:

> The reject function is a shorthand for resolving with a rejected
>   promise.

`q.fcall(throwError)` should produce a rejected promise, so the deferred should be rejected, right?

Please note that this is a purely hypothetical question, I know that this would not be used in the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be around the language used, so I'm going to try to break it down a bit more to make it clearer. When you call

```
var rejected = q.fcall(throwError);
```

then `rejected` is indeed a rejected promise. What you are then doing is

```
var def = q.defer();
def.promise.then(
  function(arg1) {
    console.log("no error");
  },
  function(arg2) {
    console.log("error");
  }
);

rejected.then(
  function(){
    def.resolve();
  },
  function(err){
    def.resolve(err); // err === new Error();
  }
);
```

When a promise is rejected, it will run the rejection callback, triggering `def.resolve(err);`. Q has no knowledge that `def` is anything other that some random arugment, so you might as well be calling `def.resolve('random');`. You are resolving `def` with some argument. In this case, it happens to be an instance of `Error`. That means that your `no error` callback will be called, and `arg1 === new Error()`.

So now, given the documentation quote you mentioned

> The reject function is a shorthand for resolving with a rejected promise.

what are you are doing is essentially transforming the rejected promise `rejected` into the promise `def.promise` which will always be fulfilled, but where the fulfillment handler will receive an error as the first argument.

To achieve what you are expecting, you need to properly make `def.promise` be rejected. You can accomplish this two ways.

1. Reject it using `def.reject(err);`.
2. As your quote says, resolve it with a rejected promise, `def.resolve(rejected);`.

Comment: Actually I wanted to use `def.resolve` twice. As I stated above, resolving with a rejected promise should trigger the error handler, not the fulfillment handler. So, IMO, the second function should be called, not the first one.

Comment: @raffomania Sorry, not following. `q.fcall(throwError)` does produce a rejected promise as you say, but since you have passed `def.resolve` as the error handler, it will resolve `def` without an error, just like if you called `def.resolve()` somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is around `resolving with a rejected promise.` What you are doing now is resolving with an `Error` object, not resolving with a rejected promise.

Comment: Please have a look here: [Using deferreds in q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds). There you can see exactly my example. `q.fcall` should produce a rejected promise, not an error.

Comment: @raffomania Correct, the return value of `fcall` returns a rejected promise. Then you are calling `.then`, which extracts the error associated with the rejection, and you pass that error as the first argument. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Now I understand. It seems so clear to me, I can't believe I didn't see this before. Thank you very much for this thorough explanation!